# Remove rows with missing values denoted by '?'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, missing-data

I have a `.csv` file that contains rows with missing values. Those values instead of `null`, are denoted by the character `?`.

How can I remove the rows that contain at least one column with value `?`, given that `df.na.drop()` won't work (since the missing values are not `null`) ?

The data looks like below (I've got 35 columns - missing values can be found in any of those columns)

```
+-------+--------+------+-------+
| col_1 | col_2  |  ... | col_35|
+-------+--------+------+-------+
| 0.75  |   ?    |  ... |   15  |
|   ?   | Helen  |  ... |   21  |
| -1.2  | George |  ... |    ?  |
|   ?   | Andrew |  ... |   129 |
| 0.12  | Maria  |  ... |   12  |   // Should not be deleted
+-------+--------+------+-------+
```

And here's the code that reads the file.

```
val df = sparkSession.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
    .load("data.csv")
    .toDF()
```

Answer (score 5):

If `?` denotes missing values you just configure the reader to recognize that:

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "?")  // Use "?" as null character
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .load("data.csv")
  .toDF()
```

and use standard `na.drop`:

```
df.na.drop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `?` to `null` values using UDFs in spark data frames.

Sample code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val df = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(("a", "B", "c"), ("D", "e", "?"), ("G", "?", "I"))).toDF("x", "y", "z")
// Function returns the input itself or null if it is a '?'
def replace: (String => String) = { value => if (value == "?") null else value }
// We create a UDF of that function because we want to run this on the entire column
val replaceudf = udf(replace)
Apply the method to all columns of the data frame
df.select(df.columns.map(c => replaceudf(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)

df.show
/* Output
+---+----+----+
|  x|   y|   z|
+---+----+----+
|  a|   B|   c|
|  D|   e|null|
|  G|null|   I|
+---+----+----+
*/
```

Now you can apply all the NA operations on the data frame. I hope this helps.

Comment: You can skip UDF here: `df.columns.map(c => when(coalesce(col(c) =!= "?", lit(false)), col(c)))`.